# Передать значение переменной php в js

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Сайт на WordPress, задача была задать разные стили элементам взависимостри от времени суток и дня недели (с этим справился), вопрос вот в чем.

Мне нужно было получать именно серверное время, а не время на стороне клиента, поэтому я вывел время с помощью php `<?php $blogtime = current_time('mysql');?>`, так же создал переменную php `$weekDay = current_time('D');`.

Когда я определил время в переменную вышеописанным способом в файле functions.php (если что, то каждая функция к файлу functions.php подключается отдельно этой командой, например `require get_template_directory() . '/functions/widgets.php';`), то вывести на страницу я эту переменную `$weekDay` не смог, пришлось создавать переменную php непосредственно в файлах темы (footer.php) и там же передавать значение переменной php в переменную js в теге `<script>var weekDay = "<?php echo $weekDay; ?>";</script>`, ну и уже только потом я в отдельном файле javascript делал манипуляции необходимые с переменными.

Подскажите, что нужно сделать, чтобы работать с переменными php и js в данной ситуации не в шаблонах темы, а в файлах функций и скриптов? Какие я допустил ошибки? Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь сформулировать вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен не только вам, но и окружающим.

Comment: @Pyramidhead что конкретно непонятно? Старался писать доступно

Comment: Непонятно, собственно, всё. Написанное очень сложно воспринимается, так как всё это больше похоже на поток сознания, чем на вопрос.

Comment: @Pyramidhead Есть сайт на WordPress, нужно получить текущее время сервера с помощью php и присвоить это значение в переменную js, я смог это сделать лишь в шаблонах темы, но не смог в файлах functions.php

Comment: Вот так и напишите в вопросе и приведите пример кода, демонстрирующий как вы выводите время в файлах тем, а также напишите, зачем вам нужно это в functions.php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

functions.php вызывается на самом раннем этапе, никакой прямой вывод из нее через `<script></script>` невозможен. А когда выводится футер, то да, там можно воткнуть скрипт.

Только это все неправильно. Для передачи параметров в скрипт есть `wp_localize_script()`. Вот эту функцию можно и нужно вызывать в functions.php во время события `wp_enqueue_script`.

Почитать об этой функции на русском можно [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_localize_script).

Comment: только что протестировал даже, все вышло! большое спасибо за пояснение